# Ошибка при запуске тестов программы на c# на apple silicon

Tags: c#, .net, apple

В Rider(и в visual studio) для MacOS при запуске тестов программы в терминале появляется следующее сообщение:

```
Test not run

Last runner error: Test runner agent exited unexpectedly Process /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet:12862 exited with code '150': It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' (arm64) was not found. 
- The following frameworks were found: 6.0.2 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App] 6.0.3 at [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App] 
You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK. The specified framework can be found at: - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=arm64&rid=osx.12-arm64
```

Проблема в том, что на указанном сайте сборок .net 3.1 для apple silicon нету. Что можно сделать? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Ну там же прямо ссылка указана, откуда можно поставить нужный фреймворк

Comment: Проблема в том, что на указанном сайте сборок .net 3.1 для apple silicon нету.

Comment: @ТимофейЧаура Для чего вам нужен c#? Я бы посоветовал использовать сразу виртуальную машину, могу рассказать про варианты